# Generating XML from my DSL

Tags: dsl, xtext

I need to write a DSL in Xtext, that is going to simplify some existing XML language. In other words I need to write DSL and then somehow translate it into XML using Xtext. So far I wrote a grammar, but my problem is how to generate an XML based on it. Do you know any tutorials on how to do something similar? Especially I have trouble with the fact that when I create new Xtext project it doesnt generate projectcame.generator project as shown in most of the tutorials.

Comment: you may be interested in my post http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2012/07/xtext-xml.html (example code at https://github.com/vorburger/xtext-sandbox/tree/master/Xtext-XML)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Xtext 2.2.

The dedicated generator project was replaced by a generator that is part of language infrastructure directy. You may want to digg into the yourdsl.generator package in your runtime plugin. There you'll find a stub implementation that takes the EMF resource and allows to create text from that. The Statemachine example uses that approach to generate Java code, but you can also produce XML or whatever you want from that.

If your XML matches a specific schema, you could of course transform your model to a valid instance of the target model and serialize that with EMF standard features, e.g. XMLResource.save().

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could byte-enhance your generated EMF Java model with JiBX, and then use a JiBX mapping to the XML you want. That might be overkill for your model, though (it depends on how complex your target documents are).

I have to warn you that I haven't done this on EMF classes; my project first translated my EMF model into an existing POJO model which was enhanced with JiBX. But assuming that they'll behave, it should work.